# SQL Server audit extended event metadata change

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, t-sql

We have extended event running in SQL Server 2014. We also have a task that run every few minutes and check that the Xevent is running -> Audit the Xevent trace.

I'm trying to find a way (in T-SQL) to audit also changes on the Xevent metadata.
If the Xevent change (by alter), or drop and create.

No need to monitor stop and start session.

I thought about hash function on the Xevent metadata, but I can not find a T-SQL way to get the Xevent string.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the Xevent metadata by using PowerShell SQLPS module.
Then Hash function on the string result:

```
    $server="localhost"
    Import-Module sqlps -DisableNameChecking
    CD SQLSERVER:\
    CD xevent\$server\default\Sessions
    $xe=Get-ChildItem |Where-Object {$_.name -eq $XeName}
    #$xe.Targets
    #$xe.IsRunning
    $Xeventmetadata=$xe.ScriptCreate().GetScript()
    $Xeventmetadata

#Getting String hash value
function Hash($textToHash)
{
    $hasher = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed
    $toHash = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($textToHash)
    $hashByteArray = $hasher.ComputeHash($toHash)
    foreach($byte in $hashByteArray)
    {
         $res += $byte.ToString()
    }
    return $res;
}
Hash("$Xeventmetadata")
```